# Refreshing, Copying and Overwriting Excel Files

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel file with multiple queries which are coming from a production database, set up as a Microsoft query. This excel file is then uploaded to a dashboard registry file which is linked to a shop dashboard. 
At the moment I have to do everything manually to update the dashboard, but I would like to automate this possibly using PowerShell.

Here is what I am currently doing manually:

- open the excel file and "refresh all" data to refresh the queries
- save the excel file
- copy the excel file from desktop
- past and overwrite the excel file into the dashboard registry folder - located within C: drive of computer

I would like this to be set up to do this process automatically on 15 minute intervals.

Can anyone offer me some advice on how to write my PowerShell script to do this successfully? (I've never used PowerShell before)

Answer (score 0):

You can open, read and edit a excel file using the [COM interface](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html). To copy the file, use the [Copy-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113292) cmdlet. To execute the script on an intervall, take a look at the [Scheduled Job cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849778.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).